# Use [Authorize] attribute with user's email

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I've seen the `[Authorize]` attribute take an AuthorizeAttribute.User property like this `[Authorize("User=Alice, Bob")]` (where `Alice`/`Bob` are usernames, I guess?). However, in my app all I register is the user's email address.

Does `[Authorize("User=...")]` take other properties? Can it take email (and do `[Authorize("User=alice@example.org, bob@example.org")]`? Not surprisingly, the [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) was not very helpful.

It's this functionality built-in, or will I have to implement my own custom Authorize attribute? Is there any documentation for a full parameter list on the Authorize attribute past the very scanty MSDN page I linked above?

Comment: Authorizez dosn't care if the user name is a login or email.

Comment: If you are using the out of box Identity provider, Emails are Usernames.

Comment: You might be better looking at doing it for 'Roles' as opposed to a 'Firstname'. Your roles could be Admin, Standard, Enhanced, etc and you would simple assign the roles in the same manner. How would you deal with a Controller action having to deal with multiple people with different names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see no difference here... "james.doe@example.com" is a string, just as much  "James Doe" is a string, both being used on the User property.

That said if you want to have your own property, e.g.`UserName` then simply derive a new Attribute class from the `Authorize` attribute and add your own properties with your own authorization logic.

Resources:

- [MVC 4: Authorization Attribute (PluralSight Video)](http://pluralsight.com/training/Player?author=scott-allen&name=mvc4-building-m7-security&mode=live&clip=6&course=mvc4-building)
- [MVC 5: Authorization Attribute (PluralSight Video)](http://pluralsight.com/training/Player?author=scott-allen&name=aspdotnet-mvc5-fundamentals-m3-identity&mode=live&clip=3&course=aspdotnet-mvc5-fundamentals)
- [ASP.NET MVC Security](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security)

---

## Example of: Custom Authorization Attribute

---

### HomeController.cs

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [CustomAuthorize(FirstNames = "Aydin")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

---

### ApplicationUser.cs   ||    User.cs

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<User> manager)
    {
        ClaimsIdentity userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("FirstName", this.FirstName));
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

---

### CustomAuthorizeAttribute.cs

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    private static readonly char[] SplitParameter = new char[1] {','};
    private string firstNames;
    private string[] firstNamesSplit = new string[0];

    public string FirstNames 
    {
        get { return this.firstNames ?? string.Empty; }
        set
        {
            this.firstNames = value;
            this.firstNamesSplit = SplitString(value);
        }
    }

    /// <summary> Called when a process requests authorization. </summary>
    public virtual void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
        }

        if (OutputCacheAttribute.IsChildActionCacheActive(filterContext))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot use with a ChildAction cache");
        }

        if (filterContext.ActionDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof (AllowAnonymousAttribute), true) ||
            filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof (AllowAnonymousAttribute), true))
        {
            return;
        }

        if (this.AuthorizeCore(filterContext.HttpContext))
        {
            HttpCachePolicyBase cache = filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache;
            cache.SetProxyMaxAge(new TimeSpan(0L));
            cache.AddValidationCallback(this.CacheValidateHandler, null);
        }
        else
            this.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
    }

    /// <summary> When overridden, provides an entry point for custom authorization checks. </summary>
    protected virtual bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (httpContext == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("httpContext");

        IPrincipal user = httpContext.User;
        if (!user.Identity.IsAuthenticated) return false;

        string claimValue = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("FirstName").Value;
        return this.firstNamesSplit.Length <= 0 ||
               this.firstNamesSplit.Contains(claimValue, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }

    private void CacheValidateHandler(HttpContext context, object data, ref HttpValidationStatus validationStatus)
    {
        validationStatus = this.OnCacheAuthorization(new HttpContextWrapper(context));
    }

    /// <summary> Processes HTTP requests that fail authorization. </summary>
    protected virtual void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
    }

    /// <summary>  Called when the caching module requests authorization. </summary>
    /// <returns>  A reference to the validation status.  </returns>
    protected virtual HttpValidationStatus OnCacheAuthorization(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (httpContext == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("httpContext");
        return !this.AuthorizeCore(httpContext)
            ? HttpValidationStatus.IgnoreThisRequest
            : HttpValidationStatus.Valid;
    }

    private string[] SplitString(string original)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(original)) return new string[0];

        return original.Split(SplitParameter)
            .Select(splitItem => new
            {
                splitItem,
                splitItemTrimmed = splitItem.Trim()
            })
            .Where (value => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.splitItemTrimmed))
            .Select(value => value.splitItemTrimmed).ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Learned this through experience, very simple to test though, is your aim to have your own property? Or to take advantage of what's already implemented by Microsoft

Comment: No. I'm frustrated with the very little documentation out there and would like to understand the User parameter here and use the best implementation for my use case.

Comment: What I found helpful when I initially started were videos from PluralSight, this particular one may provide some insight... [PluralSight MVC4 Security-Authorize](http://pluralsight.com/training/Player?author=scott-allen&name=mvc4-building-m7-security&mode=live&clip=6&course=mvc4-building)  and this [PluralSight MVC5 Security-Authorize](http://pluralsight.com/training/Player?author=scott-allen&name=aspdotnet-mvc5-fundamentals-m3-identity&mode=live&clip=3&course=aspdotnet-mvc5-fundamentals). Also skip MSDN... this is what you're looking for [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security)

Comment: Aydin, do you have any implementation details on how Authorize does the look up on the User object? If you do, could you add it to your answer?

Comment: Ive actually just left home typing from my mobile.... I can add it when i get back home in a couple of hours... In the mean time i can give you a quick overview. When you first authenticate yourself, the identity framework ciphers your credentials and roles and stores them as a cookie on the client machine. When you next visit your website again before your action executed its routes to the auth filter. The filter checks that your credentials stored in your cookie hits a match with the constraints specified in the auth attribute

Comment: Thanks, that'd be useful. But I'm more interested in a list of properties that could be accessed in the User object.

Comment: Added the custom implementation... Added a property called FirstName to the `ApplicationUser`, and then started authenticating clients based on `FirstName`

Comment: Pretty sweet. +1 For using Claims

Comment: So, simply using the email in `[Authorize] ` didn't work :( Would you mind taking a look at this [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35296699/2112866) I posted on the problem? As elegant as your custom attribute is, I'm trying to keep things as simple as possible.

Comment: @seebiscuit I'm going to get back to you on this soon, I need to replicate what you have and see if I can identify what could be going wrong.