# Authorize Attribute Not working in Web API 2.2 using OAuth2

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, oauth, oauth-2.0

I'm placing an `[Authorize(Users = "user@sample.com")]` attribute at the top of my Controller:

```
[Authorize(Users = @"user@sample.com")]
public class PostsController : ApiController
{
   ... methods...
}
```

The user's usernames are the email address. When I sign in with `user@sample.com` I still get a 401 Unauthorized this controller's methods.

I've also notice that, even after the user signs in both `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` and `System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identity.Name` are `null`.

These are a few related classes:

## ApplicationUser.cs

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string Hometown { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager, string authenticationType)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, authenticationType);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

## ApplicationDbContext

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("MyProjectEntitiesIdentity", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

The issue happens on my local dev instance as well as on the hosted site.

I know this is very vague, I just don't know what other issues may be relevant here. So, please ask for more information and I will update the post.

Comment: Have you tried changing a username to something simple, e.g. paul ... in other words try removing the @ symbol and the fullstop?

Comment: No. I would really like to understand what `[Authorize(Users = "")]` is doing, though.

Comment: Forget that, the @ symbol should be fine... This post may prove helpful to you... look at the custom attribute... implement it... then debug it... and find your issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35254833/use-authorize-attribute-with-users-email

Comment: That's my post. Lol. I'm trying to avoid all of that...